# Spring MVC how to avoid reloading page after insert to a database

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a form which takes input using text input and a controller for adding that to a database table

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/stuff/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStuff(@ModelAttribute("someForm") @Valid Stuff 
stuff,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model){

    //code for inserting to a database
    session.persist(stuff);
    return null;
}
```

I am calling this function using ajax as follows:

```
$('#somebutton').click(function () {
e.stopPropagation();
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/stuff/add',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  success: function () {
    alert(data);
  }
});
return null;
});
```

The data is inserted successfully. However, I am getting an error as the controller is trying to redirect to `/stuff/add`

```
HTTP Status 404 - /app/WEB-INF/views/stuff/add.jsp
```

My context.xml has the entry

```
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

I tried changing the return type of addStuff to **void**. However, I got the same error message.

How do I insert to the database without redirecting or refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `@ResponseBody` annotation on top of your method and change the return type to `ResponseEntity<String>`.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/stuff/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public ResponseEntity<String> addStuff(@ModelAttribute("someForm") @Valid Stuff 
stuff,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model){
//code for insert
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"msg\":\"success\"}", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and return some string/boolean in this method and then check that string in AJAX success function and based on the response you decide to redirect by using

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data.msg == "success"){
      window.location.href = "redirectURL";
    }
    alert(data);
  }
```

Comment: I am getting the value true printed on the scree and nothing else. Also, I believe the redirection is still happening here..

Comment: ResponseBody returns the response to the calling environment so in your case it should return inside ajax success function but it is returning to browser instead. Find out why?

Comment: check now..i have edited answer by changing return type to string and sending valid json from controller.